# Discontinuity of the topologist's sine curve

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin(\frac{1}{x}) &\quad x \neq 0\\0 &\quad x = 0\end{cases}$$

What is the common way of showing that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at 0, using only basic (open set) continuity arguments?

The epsilon-delta approach, if $\epsilon = 0.1$, and for any $\delta$ we can find $x$ such that $|x|<\delta \Rightarrow \sin(x) \geq 0.1$

But with open-set argument (a faulty proof): Let $V \ni 0$ be an open set. $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a union of open intervals. The pre-image $f^{-1}(( a, b )) = \cup_i (x_i, y_i): a = f(x_i), b = f(y_i)$ is an arbitrary union of open sets, hence open and f continuous at every point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the *common* way, but it works, so why not.

Take $V = (-1/2, 1/2)$, and look at $U = f^{-1}(V)$. If $f$ was continuous, then $U$ would be open, but it's not. The reason is that we have $0 \in U$, but no interval containing $0$ is in $U$, since the sequence $\frac{1}{(n + 1/2)\pi}$ is not in $U$ for any $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The pre-image of a sufficient small open set $V$ containing $0$ is a set which is an union of $\{0\}$ and open sets containing $\frac{1}{\pi k}$, $k\in \mathbb Z$\ $\{0\}$